# I need the age of my agents before they die to create a list and histogram

Tags: list, histogram, netlogo

Sorry but I am new to Netlogo, here is my problem:

I have created polar bears, who have better chances to survive on ice than on dirt. I am wondering which effect the ice dirt ratio has on the lifespan of the polar bears.
For that I need a list of the polar bears age before they die and create a histogramm with it.

I am greatful for any help.

I got told to use the comand lput, but to be honest I dont quite know how that comand works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lput` is used to append a value to a list. It reports a new list with the value appended at the end of the list. So every time before one of your polar bears dies (`die`), you want to add the age of that bear to a list and store this new list using `set`.

What you need to do

1. initialize a list during simulation setup, e.g. `set age-death-list []`
2. add the age of bears to the list when they die, e.g. `set age-death-list lput age age-death-list`
3. plot this list as a histogram in the GUI, e.g. `histogram age-death-list`

Here you find examples and syntax on how to use [lput](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#lput) and [histogram](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/histogram.html).